# python - stumped by pandas conditionals and/or boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean, conditional-statements

I am having trouble with conditionals / boolean indexing. I am trying to populate a dataframe (dfp) with logic which is conditional on data from a similarly shaped dataframe (dfs) plus the previous row of itself (dfp). 
This is my latest fail...

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0],'b':[0,1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0]})

In [171]: dfs
Out[171]: 
       a  b
    0  1  0
    1  0  1
    2 -1  0
    3  0  0
    4  1 -1
    5  0  0
    6  0  1
    7 -1  0
    8  0 -1
    9  0  0

dfp = pd.DataFrame(index=dfs.index,columns=dfs.columns)

dfp[(dfs==1)|((dfp.shift(1)==1)&(dfs!=-1))] = 1

In [166]: dfp.fillna(0)
Out[166]: 
     a    b
0  1.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0
2  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0
4  1.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0
6  0.0  1.0
7  0.0  0.0
8  0.0  0.0
9  0.0  0.0
```

So I would like dfp to have a 1 in row n if either of 2 conditions are met:

```
1) dfs same row = 1 or 2) both dfp previous row = 1 and dfs same row <> -1
```

I would like my final output to look like this:

```
   a  b
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  0  1
3  0  1
4  1  0
5  1  0
6  1  1
7  0  1
8  0  0
9  0  0
```

UPDATE / EDIT: 
Sometimes the visual is more helpful - below is how it would map out in Excel.

[image]

Thanks in advance, very grateful for your time.

Comment: Maybe if you explained the logic.  I think the -1 mean to shift up correct?  However, I don't understand the 1 in column A for index 5.

Comment: Noted, Scott. Fixed - sorry for being so vague.

Comment: Where is [a][6] coming from? (in your desired output)

Comment: Austin - dfp.ix[6,a] should = 1 because (dfp.ix[5,a]==1) & (dfs.ix[6,a]!=-1) - see above, updated to be more clear.

Comment: @MJS To me, it looks like row 5 is 0,0. Are you thinking that the processing of the rows is interdependent?

Comment: Austin - yes, interdependent. All I can come up with is that reaching to the previous row of dfp to process the current row of dfp is fouling it up.

Comment: If row [6,a] is one, by logic df.shift(1)==1 even row 7,8,9 should be 1

Comment: A-Z I don't think that's correct because multiple conditions must be met...  (1) dfs same row = 1 ---or--- 2) BOTH dfp previous row = 1 AND dfs same row <> -1. so dfp.ix[7,a] == 0 even though dfp.ix[6,a]==1 because dfs.ix[7,a] == -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's summarize the invariants:

- If the `dfs` value is `1` then the `dfp` value is `1`.
- If the `dfs` value is `-1` then the `dfp` value is `0`.
- If the `dfs` value is `0` then the `dfp` value is `1` if the previous `dfp` value is `1` otherwise it's `0`.

Or to formulate in another way:

- The `dfp` starts with `1` if the first value is `1`, otherwise `0`
- The `dfp` values are `0` until there is a `1` in `dfs`.
- The `dfp` values are `1` until there is a `-1` in `dfs`.

This is very easy to formulate in python:

```
def create_new_column(dfs_col):
    newcol = np.zeros_like(dfs_col)
    if dfs_col[0] == 1:
        last = 1
    else:
        last = 0
    for idx, val in enumerate(dfs_col):
        if last == 1 and val == -1:
            last = 0
        if last == 0 and val == 1:
            last = 1
        newcol[idx] = last

    return newcol
```

And the test:

```
>>> create_new_column(dfs.a)
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
>>> create_new_column(dfs.b)
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

However this is very inefficient in Python because iterating over numpy-arrays (and pandas Series/DataFrames) is slow and the `for`-loops in python are inefficient as well.

However if you have `numba` or `Cython` you can compile this and it will be (probably) faster than any NumPy solution could be, because NumPy would require several rolling and/or accumulate operations.

For example with numba:

```
>>> import numba
>>> numba_version = numba.njit(create_new_column)  # compilation step

>>> numba_version(np.asarray(dfs.a))  # need cast to np.array
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
>>> numba_version(np.asarray(dfs.b))  # need cast to np.array
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Even if `dfs` has millions of rows the numba solution will take only milliseconds:

```
>>> dfs = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(-1, 2, 1000000),'b':np.random.randint(-1, 2, 1000000)})
>>> %timeit numba_version(np.asarray(dfs.b))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.37 ms per loop
```

Comment: thanks MSeifert (and jezrael). I am trying to apply your logic now - haven't used numba before.

Comment: MSeifert - i have reproduced the results and your solution is the fastest i have seen so far. Thanks.

Comment: @MJS You're welcome. Did it work with numba? If not I can probably also find another (slower than numba but faster than python) solution.

Comment: It did work with numba, very cool. thanks again for your time, i will accept your answer.

Comment: @MSeifert - very nice solution ;) +100 ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not the best way to do it but something that works.

```
    dfs = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0],'b':[0,1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0]})
    dfp = dfs.copy()
```

Define the function as follows. Usage of 'last' here is a little hacky.

```
    last = [0]
    def f( x ):
         if x == 1:
             x = 1
         elif x != -1 and last[0] == 1:
             x = 1
         else:
             x = 0
         last[0] = x
         return x
```

Simply apply the func f on each column.

```
    dfp.a = dfp.a.apply( f )
    dfp

       a  b
    0  1  0
    1  1  1
    2  0  0
    3  0  0
    4  1 -1
    5  1  0
    6  1  1
    7  0  0
    8  0 -1
    9  0  0
```

Similarly for col b. Don't forget to re-initalize 'last'.

```
    last[0] = 0
    dfp.b = dfp.b.apply( f )
    dfp
       a  b
    0  1  0
    1  1  1
    2  0  1
    3  0  1
    4  1  0
    5  1  0
    6  1  1
    7  0  1
    8  0  0
    9  0  0
```

Comment: thanks very much vara - i up voted your solution which worked well, produced accurate results. the results were slightly slower than the non-compiled above.