# How do I turn objects or values in pandas df into boolean?

Tags: python, pandas

What I want to do is change values in a column into boolean.

What I am looking at: I have a dataset of artists with a column named "Death Year".

Within that column, it has the Death Year or `Nan` which I changed to Alive. I want to make this column where it turns the death year into false and alive value as True. dType for this column is Object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - stumped by pandas conditionals and/or boolean indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509953/python-stumped-by-pandas-conditionals-and-or-boolean-indexing)

Comment: Also see: [How to use a conditional statement based on DataFrame boolean value in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713221/how-to-use-a-conditional-statement-based-on-dataframe-boolean-value-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducible Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DeathYear':[2005,2003,np.nan,1993]})

    DeathYear
0   2005.0
1   2003.0
2   NaN
3   1993.0
```

which you turned into

```
df['DeathYear'] = df['DeathYear'].fillna('Alive')

    DeathYear
0   2005
1   2003
2   Alive
3   1993
```

You can just use

```
df['BoolDeathYear'] = df['DeathYear'] == 'Alive'

    DeathYear   BoolDeathYear
0   2005        False
1   2003        False
2   Alive       True
3   1993        False
```

*Notice that, if your final goal is to have the bool column, you don't have to fill the NaNs at all.*

Can just do

```
df['BoolDeathYear'] = df['DeathYear'].isnull()
```